# JavaScript - Moment and Date.toLocaleDateString keeps returning my time when using a different locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I started off using the Moment library to try to get the time for Germany using the following code:

```
import moment from 'moment'
import 'moment/locale/de'

moment.locale('de');
console.log(moment().format('LTS'));
```

However, it kept returning my time, British summer time (BST)

I figured maybe it was an issue with the library, so I rewrote it without using the library like so:

```
const options = { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric' }
const test = new Date();
console.log(test.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options));
```

Yet this also returns my time... (with the added date, month and year as expected)

Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe it's something to do with how Chrome outputs to the console?

Comment: Locales are only used for language-specific formatting of dates and times. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get the time in Germany.

Comment: Please note that locale != timezone, `moment.locale('de');` sets locale, but [`moment()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/) takes system local time. Use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to get time across timezones.

Comment: I never realised this, now my question seems really nooby haha. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment locale refers to language not timezone.

You'll need [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs) for that:

```
moment().tz('CET').format('LTS')
```

EDIT

As suggested by RobG, could also be achieved without moment:

```
new Date().toLocaleString('de-DE', { timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin' });
```

```js
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleString('de-DE', { timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin' });
```

```html
<div id="date"/>
```

Comment: No doubt “locale” is used to reflect its use in ECMA 402, I think it’s a misnomer. There is also a *timezone* property for the [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) method so there may not be a need for moment.tz.

Answer (score 1):

With *toLocaleString* you can use the *timeZone* option, however it may not be supported everywhere you need it to be:

```js
var options = {hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin'};
var test = new Date();
console.log(test.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it using `moment` -

```js
function toTimeZone(time, zone) {
    var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
    return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format);
}

console.log(toTimeZone(new Date(), "UTC"));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```